# Does there exist a copy of Euclid's Elements with modern notation and no figures?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, math-history

I am working through Euclid's Elements for fun, but I find the propositions difficult to understand without referencing the provided figures. Unfortunately, the figures usually give away the proofs, so sometimes I feel robbed of the opportunity to work on a fun problem. Does anyone know of an edition of Euclid's Elements that uses modern mathematical language AND does not have figures? I've been searching for a few hours and haven't found anything. If no one can think of anything and someone is interested in a "Euclid through Inquiry" style document, then I might spend a weekend $\TeX$ing something up.

This is my first stack-exchange post, so I am sorry if this question is inappropriate.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I don't know of any, but I wanted to say that I really appreciate the sentiment that if this doesn't exist, then you're willing to go out and make it. (If you do, I encourage you to answer your own question here with a link to it, so that others know).

Comment: What about visiting a website like [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/bookI.html) and turning off Java (all the figures seem to use some sort of Java applet, so turning off Java would, as far as I can tell, remove them)?

Comment: @mixedmath - Thanks for the welcome! I will definitely link to any resource that I find, whether I create it or not.

Comment: @mtjoseph - Thanks for the suggestion. I go to that site often for its excellent discussion of each proposition. I never thought to turn off Java. Unfortunately, that still leaves the problem of some Propositions being indecipherable to me without the figures. Consider Proposition 35: "Parallelograms which are on the same base and in the same parallels equal one another". In modern phrasing, Euclid claims that parallelograms with equal base length and height have equal _area_, but I would not have rralized that without the figure.

Comment: @David I know that is not exactly what you want but I believe you can provide the same fun. Know the book of Mark Geormetria Euclidean Solomonovich? See on google http://books.google.com.br/books?id=it4Pko36IcYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Euclidean+Geometry&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=G5FYUfuuKszk4AOO94HgDg&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 4):

When I started delving in to The *Elements* I had the same issue. Euclid's propositions are somewhat unusual especially due to the translations. I actually did a whole blog post on this that was geared towards new students trying to learn and understand geometry. I go over the propositions in it if you are interested: http://mathhelpblog.com/geometry-for-dummies-how-to-do-geometry-and-understand-it/. Perhaps this could serve as an example on how to show it it more modern terms.

It's a challenging read, but I figure since it was the go-to math text for over 2000 years, that it still has its relevance. Euclid is a personal hero of mine. I know its been a while since you wrote this post, but I am interested in what you came up with.

Answer (score 3):

In general, mathematicians say that the best way to study Euclidean geometry is drawing the figures yourself following the instructions of proofs. I believe it's a valid point of view even if it is only a study for fun. And most mathematicians think that way about almost every area of mathematics. So I hardly think you will find a translation of Euclid's elements that draw all construction in each proof.

Suggestion. See the book [Euclid's elements of geometry](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=7HDWIOoBZUAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=English%20version%20of%20Euclid%27s%20Elements&hl=pt&sa=X&ei=jJJYUaaSOoWi4APfnYGQDA&redir_esc=y) by Richard Fitzparick. This book has few pictures. But I think it won't bother you.  Although the translation is accompanied by small clarifications. I think you have a modern language you seek.

Answer (score 2):

After 7 years, I finally completed the supplement I was looking for back then. My problem isn't the figures per se, but the fact that the figures usually give away the solution. I created a supplement that hopefully provides enough information for a student to understand each proposition well enough to take a stab at it themselves.

LaTeX: https://github.com/davidMis/euclidSupplement

PDF: https://github.com/davidMis/euclidSupplement/raw/main/out/book1.pdf

All feedback and suggestions are welcome, and I'd be overjoyed to hear if anyone finds it interesting or useful.